# find out specific keys from arrray?

Tags: php, mysql

i have an array like this

```
[multiple_name] => Array
    (
        [0] => Change the business unit\'s root business unit
        [1] => Change the business unit\'s parent business unit
        [2] => Copy the business unit to the new position in the organizational hierarchy.
        [3] => Disable the business unit, change the business unit s organization team and then activate the business unit
    )

[multiple_correct] => Array
    (
        [1] => yes
    )
```

now i want to print only key/index values from this array like '0,1,2,3' and from next one '1'.

kindly help me through this.. thanx in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `foreach` and bind the keys to a variable:

```
foreach($someArray as $key => $value) {
  echo $key;
}
```

Where I supposed (from your question) that `multiple_name` and `multiple_correct` are not nested arrays, if they are though you need to `foreach` twice:

```
foreach($containerArray as $innerArray) {
  foreach($innerArray as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
  }
}
```

Comment: yes they are nested arrays and i want to print keys of only these above arrays so i can store them and then compare them for my code.